# flask reactive table/grid with edit forms

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, datatables, htmx

With flask,what technologies/components or libraries are used to display reactive tables/grids with edit forms?

I've come across datatables and it works fine, except that I can't make the associated edit form reactive. By this, I mean good old in-table per row action buttons (edit, delete). Click edit, a flask API serves a minimal form in an embedded div, do its business, save or cancel, and update the datables display as necessary.  I've tried incorporating htmx, but my knowledge has proven inadequate. Had this as reference :https://til.jacklinke.com/using-htmx-and-server-side-datatables-net-together-in-a-django-project. It appears the solution is outdated, besides it seems hackish as htmx is not really supported out of the box.

I started looking at vue.js in standalone script mode (no build) and it got me excited, except that it looks like I have to rebuild all functionalities of the datatables. It would be worthwhile though as the knowledge gained in this undertaking can be definitely applied to other parts of the project.

So, what does everybody use to display grid/table data that has this kind of reactivity?